# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ParagraphUtil.getFirstTabStop(ParagraphUtil.java:208)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When i tried to generating JasperReports this error occurred.
anyone know what kind of error is this?

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ParagraphUtil.getFirstTabStop(ParagraphUtil.java:208)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderNextLine(TextMeasurer.java:1023)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderParagraph(TextMeasurer.java:717)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.measure(TextMeasurer.java:416)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.chopTextElement(JRFillTextElement.java:504)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillStaticText.prepare(JRFillStaticText.java:183)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:377)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:351)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2039)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:632)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeaders(JRVerticalFiller.java:554)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:279)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:144)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:485)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:888)
```

Comment: You can look at this posts: [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ParagraphUtil.getFirstTabStop](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/2999) & [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ParagraphUtil.getFirstTabStop with multicolums and wrapped text](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541804/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-paragraphutilgetfirsttabstop-multicolums-and-wrapped) & [Preview error 4.1.2 and 4.1.3 ArrayIndexOutOfBounds](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541156/preview-error-412-and-413-arrayindexoutofbounds)

Answer (score 0):

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Is when you try access an index which is empty or exceeds the maximum or mnmum allowed index of your Array, in Example when you try to access the 5th element of an array which contains only 4 elements.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) states about this:

> **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**
>
> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in 6.2.1. check it here https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/2999-0